# PHPMailer + HTML2PDF: pdf invalid and pj

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, fpdf, html2pdf

Good morning all ,
I would like to attach a PDF created following a form with HTML2PDF then send it with PHMailer.
Everything works, the email goes well, I managed to create the PDF by saving it on my hard drive.
But when I try to attach it to my email, the pdf is fine in pj but I can't open it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHibY.jpg)

It is the same size of my locally created pdf.
I followed the tutorial and wiki of the two libraries, well I think ^^
Here is my PHPMailer code:

```html
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require './vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '******';             // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '*****';                         // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*****';                    // SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = ****;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('****@****.com', '****');
    $mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo($shop_email, 'Votre magasin');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');

    $mail->addBCC($shop_email);

    // Attachments
    $mail->addStringAttachment($pdf_done, 'myPdf.pdf');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

    $mail->send();
    echo '';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

and here is the code for HTML2PDF:

```html
ob_start();
// --> mon code HTML de creeation du PDF
$content = ob_get_clean();

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

try{
    $pdf = new \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $pdf->writeHTML($content);

    $pdf_done = $pdf->output('myPdf.pdf', 'S');

}catch(\Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException $e){
    die($e);
}

?>
```

I tried adding ", 'base64', 'application / pdf'" in the addStringAttachment but it doesn't change anything.
Do you have any idea of my mistake?

Thank you all

Comment: I can see that the image in your image description here is a popup with some french text describing the problem encountered, can you perhaps put the french text in and give an approximate translation as to what it says, and change the link translation to be something meaningful?  I think this would improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Debug one thing at a time. First download the PDF manually and make sure it looks correct – if the PDF is bad to start with, emailing it isn't going to improve things. Next check that it is readable from PHP – for example serve it using [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/readfile). Then when you try to attach it, check the return value of your call to `addAttachment()` like this:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment('/path/to/myPdf.pdf')) {
    die('could not read PDF');
}
```

Also note the difference between [`addAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment) and [`addStringAttachment`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment); you're adding a file that's been saved to disk, so you want the first one, not the second.

Comment: I dont want to save it on my server, but just send it in mail attachment. Its was to build the pdf, i was recording it into my local hard drive, and its was ok, the pdf looks good. I wanted to save the pdf into a variable "$pdf_done" and put it into phpmailer with addattachment. It is possible? I try a lot of different possibilities but it is always the same, i see the pdf in the mail (92ko), but error when i want to open it :x

Comment: OK, in that case `addStringAttachment` is the correct method, but your generated PDF string needs to be in scope and generated before you try to email it – you have presented it as being a separate script, which is confusing. I'd also recommend confirming that the generated string is a valid PDF by returning it yourself: set a content type header and `echo $pdf_done`.

Comment: How can i putt a content type header into html2pdf? I include the pdf creation script first, then i include the phpmailer script, it would be correct?

Comment: You don't put it into the PDF, you set a header before sending the output – `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');`. I would recommend you put both parts of the script into one file, otherwise you may have scope problems with the variables you're passing between the two parts.